# Application cache v.s. hibernate second level cache, which to use?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, redis, memcached

I have a choice to use application cache,

that is manually cache objects to a distribute memcached/redis cluster

OR let hibernate second level cache to do the cache work (for those application object).

which to use is better?

Comment: In my opinion there are clear advantages and dissadvantages of the two aproaches therefore adequate answer is possible without being opinion based. I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: I agree with @AlexandarPetrov, But the question might need to be updated with some detail

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on your application querying model and the traffic demands.

1. Using Redis/Hazelcast may yield the best performance since there won't be any round-trip to DB anymore, but you end up having a normalized data in DB and denormalized copy in you cache which will put pressure on your cache update policies. So you gain the best performance at the cost of implementing the cache update whenever the persisted data changes.
2. Using 2nd level cache is easier to setup but it only stores entities by id. There is also a query cache, storing ids returned by a given query. So the 2nd level cache is a two step process that you need to fine tune to get the best performance. When you execute projection queries the 2nd level object cache won't help you, since it only operates on entity load. The main advantage of 2nd level cache is that it's easier to keep it in sync whenever data changes, especially if all your data is persisted by hibernate.

So, if you need ultimate performance and you don't mind implementing your cache update logic that ensures a minimum eventual consistency window, then go with an external cache.

If you only need to cache entities (that usually don't change that frequently) and you mostly access those through Hibernate entity loading, then 2nd level cache can help you.