# hibernate second level cache with Redis -will it improve performance?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, redis

I am currently developing an application using *Spring MVC4* and *hibernate 4*. I have implemented **hibernate second level cache** for performance improvement. If I use  **Redis** which is an in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache etc, the performance will increase but will it be a drastic change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drastic differences you may expect if you cache what is good to be cached and avoid caching data that should not be cached at all. Like beauty is in the eye of the beholder the same is with the performance. Here are several aspects you should have in mind when using hibernate AS second level cache provider:

**No Custom serialization - Memory intensive**
If you use second level caching, you would not be able to use fast serialization frameworks such as Kryo and will have to stick to java serializable which sucks.

On top of this for each entity type you will have a separate region and within each region, you will have an entry for each key of each entity.
In terms of memory efficiency, this is inefficient.

**Lacks the ability to store and distribute rich objects**
Most of the modern caches also present computing grid functionality having your objects fragmented into many small pieces decrease your ability to execute distributed tasks with guaranteed data co-location. That depends a little bit on the Grid provider, but for many would be a limitation.

**Sub optimal performance**
Depending on how much performance you need and what type of application you are having using hibernate second level cache might be a good or a bad choice. Good in terms that it is plug and play...." kind of..."  bad because you will never squeeze the performance you would have gained. Also designing rich models mean more upfront work and more OOP.

**Limited querying capabilities ON the Cache itself**
That depends on the cache provider, but some of the providers really are not good doing JOINs with Where clause different than the ID. If you try to build and in memory index for a query on Hazelcast, for example, you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use **Redis**, it will improve your performance.

No, it will not be a drastic change. :)

https://memorynotfound.com/spring-redis-application-configuration-example/

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

the above links will help you to find out the way of integration redis with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was already discussed here. Check this link: [Application cache v.s. hibernate second level cache, which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708905/application-cache-v-s-hibernate-second-level-cache-which-to-use)

This was the most accepted answer, which I agree with:

> It really depends on your application querying model and the traffic
> demands.
>
> 1. Using Redis/Hazelcast may yield the best performance since there won't
>    be any round-trip to DB anymore, but you end up having a normalized
>    data in DB and denormalized copy in your cache which will put pressure
>    on your cache update policies. So you gain the best performance at the
>    cost of implementing the cache update whenever the persisted data
>    changes.
> 2. Using 2nd level cache is easier to set up but it only stores
>    entities by id. There is also a query cache, storing ids returned by a
>    given query. So the 2nd level cache is a two-step process that you
>    need to fine tune to get the best performance. When you execute
>    projection queries the 2nd level object cache won't help you, since it
>    only operates on entity load. The main advantage of 2nd level cache is
>    that it's easier to keep it in sync whenever data changes, especially
>    if all your data is persisted by hibernate.
>
> So, if you need ultimate
> performance and you don't mind implementing your cache update logic
> that ensures a minimum eventual consistency window, then go with an
> external cache.
>
> If you only need to cache entities (that usually don't change that
> frequently) and you mostly access those through Hibernate entity
> loading, then 2nd level cache can help you.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the movement.

If You have 1000 or more requests per second and You are low on RAM, then Yes, use redis nodes on other machine to take some usage. It will greatly improve your RAM and request speed.

But If it's otherwise then do not use it.

Remember that You can use this approach later when You will see what is the RAM and database Connection Pool usage.